# How to solve a Nonlinear least squares problem?

Tags: matlab, optimization, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80sX6.png)

Initial idea is to use euclidean distances. But I do not understand how should I solve this task. Does anyone have some hints on how to approach this?

Comment: Is this the first of your tasks or where there others before? Do you see similiarities to the previous one? Did you successfully solve the previous one yourself? What was the key concept that you applied there?

Comment: @Yunnosch No, this is my first task.

Comment: Do you know how to do a very basic thing with matlab? Something like a HelloWorld? Even if you cannot solve the task, can you show your best attempt at getting at least close? Or would this be the first time that you use Matlab?

Comment: Please provide the textual part of your task as text in the question itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for info on suitable formatting, I recommend the "quote" formatting with `>`.

Comment: Also I recommend to sacrifice one of the selected tags in favor of "matlab".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least-squares error is obviously the sum of the squares of the differences between the computed distances from the estimated point to the bases, and the measured distances.

Now you can implement Levenberg-Marquard to minimize this objective function.

Hint: for a good initial approximation, you can solve the problem for two bases, as there is a closed-form solution. There will be two solutions, and you can discriminate using the distance to the third base.

[image]